# Syntax Error line 0, col 19: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'

Tags: php, symfony, datatable, symfony5

I am using symfony 5 php version 7.4. I am getting an error in the datatable part. I checked the controller, I checked the userdatatable part, but I could not reach a result.
I also changed the datatable version but still the same error.

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 19: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'
```

UserDatatable.php

```
use SgDatatableTrait;


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getLineFormatter()
{
    $formatter = function ($row) {
        $row['email'] = "<i class='bi bi-envelope text-success fs-4 text-primary me-2'></i> " . $row['email'];
        $row['profile']['mobilePhoneNumber'] = "<i class='bi bi-phone text-danger fs-4 me-2'></i> " . $row['profile']['mobilePhoneNumber'];

        if(@$row['profile']['totalScore']){
            $score = "-";
            if ($row['profile']['totalScore'] > 0) {
                $score = $row['profile']['totalScore'];
            }
            $row['profile']['totalScore'] = "<i class='bi bi-star-fill text-warning fs-4 me-2'></i> " . $score;
        }


        return $row;
    };
    return $formatter;
}


/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildDatatable(array $options = array())
{

    $this->setDatatableDefaults();

    $type = $options['type'];

    $this->columnBuilder
        ->add('id', Column::class, array(
            'title' => 'Id',
            'width' => "0",
            'visible' => false
        ))
        
        ->add('email', Column::class, array(
            'title' => 'E-mail',
        ))
        ->add('profile.mobilePhoneNumber', Column::class, array(
            'title' => 'Telefon',
            'default_content' => ""
        ));

    $this->columnBuilder
        ->add(null, ActionColumn::class,
            $this->addActionColumn([
                "actions" => array(
                    $this->addShowButton(array("route" => 'user_' . $type . '_show')),
                    $this->addEditButton(array("route" => 'user_' . $type . '_edit')),
                    $this->addDeleteButton(array("route" => 'user_delete')),
                )
            ]));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getEntity()
{
    return 'App\User';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'user_datatable';
}


public function getResponse($args = [])
{
    $this->datatableResponse->setDatatable($this);
    $qb = $this->datatableResponse->getDatatableQueryBuilder();
    $qb = $qb->getQb();

    $role = $args['userRole'];
    $qb->andWhere('user.roles LIKE :roles')->setParameter('roles', '%' . $role . '%');
    return $this->datatableResponse->getResponse();

}
```

If there is any code content you want me to share, I can share it.

Comment: try changing `'user.roles LIKE :roles'` to `'roles LIKE :roles'` or modify the the query builder to include an alias to `user`

Comment: I tried but still the same error